# Вывод непонятных символов. Код на Си

Tags: c

Хочу что бы выводило строку определенных символов из массива символов, но результат либо вообще не выводится если на dev-c, либо выводит странные символы если на CodeBlocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct car
{
    int year;
    int hp;
    char model[20];
    char mf[20];
};

struct car addInfo(int year, int hp, char model[], char mf[]) {
    return {year, hp, model[20], mf[20]};
}


int main(void) {
    int year;
    int hp;
    char model[20];
    char mf[20];

    printf("Enter car year: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    printf("Enter horsepower: ");
    scanf("%d", &hp);
    printf("Enter model ");
    scanf("%s", &model);
    printf("Enter manufacture ");
    scanf("%s", &mf);

    printf("%d:%d:%s:%s\n", year, hp, model, mf);
    struct car cars = addInfo(year, hp, model, mf);
    printf("%d \t %d \t %s \t %s", cars.year, cars.hp, cars.model, cars.mf);
```

[image: Здесь выводятся не понятные символы вместо Speedster, а Porsche вообще не выводится. Используется CodeBlocks]

[image: Здесь не выводятся Speedster и Porsche в последней строке. Используется Dev-c]

Comment: `return {year, hp, model[20], mf[20]};` а тут точно ошибки нет? Вроде бы надо скопировать строку было а не 20 символ её взять. Нет?

Comment: То есть мне убрать '[20]'? Тогда компилятор будет жаловаться, что "32 [Error] could not convert '{year, hp, model, mf}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'car' "

Comment: Вот что меня всегда удивляет - это неумирающая надежда, что если написать какую-то ерунду, но которую пропустит компилятор - то все будет работать так, как надо... Все равно что если дверь низковата -  ноги (или голову) рубить... *Копируйте* нужную информацию. Как копируют в С строки - знаете?

Comment: Вообще не знаю как копировать, может покажешь мне подробно?))

Comment: Может вам стоит прочитать хотябы азы перед тем как пытаться что то сделать?

Comment: Какой замечательный совет, Владимир, что бы я без тебя делал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct car addInfo(int year, int hp, char model[], char mf[]) 
{
    struct car C;
    C.year = year;
    C.hp = hp;
    strcpy(C.model,model);
    strcpy(C.mf,mf);
    return C;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно, всё работает

Comment: Может, тогда примите ответ? Вам все равно, а мне приятно..

Comment: Я думал что нажал на галку, теперь вроде точно нажал.

P.S. Мне не всё равно, спасибо ещё раз за помощь